# Delete everything from subfolders

Tags: applescript

Below is the script that I have (don't ask me how I came to this).
I know it's stupid and heavy.
I need just the simplest script to go to sub folders and delete:

1. variant. everything from it.
2. variant. .mp4 files

Without deleting sub folders.

Thank you for your help.

```
property source_folder : alias "Macintosh HD:Users:User:Pictures:4K Stogram:"
property save_folder : path to trash folder as string

# set source_folder to choose folder with prompt "Select the folder of folders containing images."
# set save_folder to choose folder with prompt "Select the folder to save the images in."

process_folder(source_folder)

on process_folder(this_folder)
    set these_items to list folder this_folder without invisibles
    set container_name to name of (info for this_folder)
    repeat with i from 1 to the count of these_items
        set this_item to alias ((this_folder as Unicode text) & (item i of these_items))
        if folder of (info for this_item) is true then
            process_folder(this_item)
        else
            process_item(this_item, container_name, i)
        end if
    end repeat
end process_folder

-- this sub-routine processes files 
on process_item(this_item, c, i)
    tell application "System Events"
        move this_item to save_folder
    end tell
end process_item
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the function "entire contents" to get all files, including recursive sub folders contents. The 6 lines script bellow replaces your complete script.

```
set SourceFolder to choose folder with prompt "Source folder"
set SaveFolder to choose folder with prompt "Save  folder"
tell application "Finder"
   set myFiles to every file of entire contents of SourceFolder
   move myFiles to SaveFolder
end tell
```

you can also filter selected files via their extensions like "mp4" by adding a filter on the 4th lines. Even more you can set a list of extensions !

```
set myFiles to every file of entire contents of SourceFolder whose name extension is "mp4"
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete every file recursively in all subfolders of a given folder but keeping the folder structure the shell command `find` is very suitable because it's much faster than the Finder.

- If the property `deleteOnlyMP4` is set to `true` only files with extension `mp4` will be moved to the trash folder.
- If the property `deleteOnlyMP4` is set to `false` all files will be moved to the trash folder.

  ```
  property deleteOnlyMP4 : true

  set source_folder to POSIX path of (path to pictures folder) & "4K Stogram"

  if deleteOnlyMP4 then
      do shell script "/usr/bin/find " & quoted form of source_folder & " -iname '*.mp4' -exec /bin/mv {} ~/.Trash \\;"
  else
      do shell script "/usr/bin/find " & quoted form of source_folder & " -type f -exec /bin/mv {} ~/.Trash \\;"
  end if
  ```